# Can you help find my mistake in deriving the gradient for this unusual log likelihood function?

Tags: gradient-descent, likelihood, derivative

I have been having some difficulty deriving a gradient of an equation.
I have a Negative log likelihood function, from which I have to derive its gradient function.
Negative log likelihood function is given as:
$$
− \log L  = −\sum_{i=1}^{M}y_{i}x_{i}θ+\sum_{i=1}^{M}e^{x_{i}θ} +\sum_{i=1}^{M}log(y_i!).
$$

Its gradient is supposed to be: $∇_θ(−\log L)=−X^T ( y−e^{Xθ}$)
where $X ∈ R^{M×N}$ is the data matrix with M the number of samples and $N$ the number of features in each input vector $x_i, y∈ I ^{M×1} $ is the scores vector and $θ ∈ R^{N×1}$ is the parameters vector.

when I'm deriving the above function for one value, I'm getting: $− \log L = x(e^{x\theta}-y)$ which is different from the actual gradient function.

Can anyone help me find my mistake?

Comment: What do the diamond shape figures with question marks inside represent?

Comment: Im not sure which ones are you referring to, this is how it looks to me: https://ibb.co/jz5VftX